# Android Default textselector to copy text not working

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-custom-view, custom-view

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0
        at  android.text.SpannableStringInternal.checkRange(SpannableStringInternal.java:355) 
        at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:77)
        at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan(SpannableString.java:46)
        at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionEndHandleView.updateSelection(Editor.java:3485)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:3173)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:3157)
        at android.widget.Editor$SelectionEndHandleView.updatePosition(Editor.java:3500)
        at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:3266)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7736)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7916)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4023)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3471)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3452)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5588)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5559)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5737)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5710)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5756)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
&PRODUCT=ghost_retasia&DISPLAY=0.currentSizeRange.smallest=[720,670]
```

I am getting this error when i am clicking on text view in android to copy selected text.two selector handle at same position  pointing and when i try to move them i m getting this force close.
also sometime my

> textisselectable=true

this functionality not work on few devices? i Google  but i have not found any relevant working solution.
I have custom listview i want to copy content of custom row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to Html.fromttext or links. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=137509